# Facebook error Include of non-modular header inside framework module

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am getting the following error when i tried to integrate Parse.com and Facebook SDK.

The error is as follows:

[image]

The library files that i added.

[image]

Update - After changing `YES` to `"Allow non-modular includes in Framework modules"`

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to Build Settings and search for "Allow non-modular includes in Framework modules" and change it to `YES`

Comment: I have got 2 more errors after said `YES` to  `Allow non-modular includes in Framework modules`. Help

Comment: have you cleaned your project? I just added the new Facebook SDK to my project yesterday and I just did that and it's working now, but the thing is I haven't used the ParseUI framework. I'm not really sure now what's the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 9):

If you are developing with Swift you have to remove the ".modulemap" file under the "Modules" folder in every framework from Facebook you have included. 
That worked for me.

See this link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#xcode_link

Comment: THIS. After a lot of searching, this was the only thing that solved my problem!